# SSL Certificates installed on my site. but still browser shows unsafe connection

Tags: apache, ssl

I have installed ssl certificates on my site but the browsers still showing unsafe connection. However i can access a safe connection by using https:// before site url

Comment: What web server? IIS? Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *force* https you'll need to set that up.

As explained on the [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) the recommended method is to setup the http virtual host to redirect to the https virtual host. Alternatively, you can use mod_rewrite to redirect from http to https.

Comment: As explained in [this answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/28443/11628), forcing the `http://` to `https://` redirection only mitigates the risk, if you're already on a trusted network. If you really want to secure the access, your users should expect to use `https://` in the first place: they're ultimately the only ones who can make sure they're using it.